# RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Connecting state

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious, tediousjs

Using Tedious to connect to MSSQL DB. In the code below, I get the error:

`RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Connecting state`

```
exports.exec_sql_cmd = async function(cmd)
{
var config = {  
    server: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    authentication: {
        type: 'ntlm',
        options: {
            userName: 'master',
            password: 'masterp',
   domain: 'the.domain.com'
        }
    },
    options: {            
        encrypt: false,
        database: 'tblTest'
    }
};  
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function(err) { 
    console.log("Connected");  
    executeStatement();
});
connection.connect();
 
function executeStatement() {  
var request = new Request(cmd, function(err) {  
 if (err) {  
    console.log(err);}  
});  

request.on('row', function(columns) {  
    columns.forEach(function(column) {  
      if (column.value === null) {  
        console.log('NULL');  
      } else {  
        console.log("Row Inserted");  
      }  
    });  
});

request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
    connection.close();
});
connection.execSql(request);  
}

}
```

`

I do get connected (this line runs: `console.log("Connected");` ), but then this error is thrown:
RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the Connecting state

I have also tried it this way, below, but this throws the error: `ERROR ConnectionError: Failed to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:1433 in 15000ms`

```
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function(err) { 
    console.log("I Am Connected!");  
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err)
      return callback(err, null);

    const request = new Request(sql, (rerr, rowCount, rows) => {
        
      if (rerr)
        {
            console.log("THIS IS THE ERROR: " + rerr)
            return callback(rerr, null)
        }

        callback(null, {rowCount, rows});
    });

    request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
        connection.close();
    });

    connection.execSql(request);
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you `telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 1433` from the Node machine? Sounds like the SQL Server isn't accessible: in SQL Server Configuration Manager does the instance have the TCP/IP protocol enabled, is it listening on tcp/1433? Does Windows Firewall allow incoming connections to tcp/1433? Are network firewall/s allowing incoming connections to tcp/1433? Do you know - for certain - that the target SQL Server accepts NTLM authentication? That would be unusual and requires additional ports to be opened depending on whether it's NTLM or NTLMv2.

Comment: The first code sample prints `Connected` to the console because it doesn't actually check if an error occurred.